# R - Dataframe values inside mysql query in R

Tags: sql, r, dataframe

In R - Is it possible to make a mysql query with a IN, where the values in that IN are from a DataFrame column?

EXAMPLE of what I'm trying to do:

```
Directory = read.csv("worlddirectory.csv", header = TRUE, sep = ",",stringsAsFactors=FALSE)

Active_Customers = Directory[(Directory$Status == "Active"),]

PhoneNumbers = dbGetQuery(DBConnection,
"
Select
db.phonenumbers,
db.names
from
database db
where
db.country IN
(
Active_Customers$Country
);"
```

Answer (score 2):

As we can see [here](https://www.w3schools.com/sql/sql_in.asp), the expected statement looks like:

```
WHERE column_name IN (value1, value2, ...);
```

We can use `paste` with the argument `collapse=", "` to obtain the desired format. I think this should work:

```
PhoneNumbers = dbGetQuery(DBConnection,
paste0("SELECT db.phonenumbers, db.names ",
"FROM database db ",
"WHERE db.country IN (",
       paste(Active_Customers$Country,collapse=", "),");"))
```

Example:

```
Active_Customers <- data.frame(Country=c("NL","BE","US"))

paste0("SELECT db.phonenumbers, db.names ",
"FROM database db ",
"WHERE db.country IN (",
paste(Active_Customers$Country,collapse=", "),");")
```

Output:

```
[1] "SELECT db.phonenumbers, db.names FROM database db WHERE db.country IN (NL, BE, US);"
```

Hope this helps!

Comment: I do this as well, tho in a context where SQL injection is essentially not a concern.